# Any recent success installing and using slic3r on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux

I have a 3d printer and two raspberry pis. I use one as my main desktop computer and the other I keep plugged in to the 3d printer, running octopi.

I am a newbie to 3d printing. I have STL files but I see that I need a slicing software to convert STL files to gcode which I can then feed to octopi to print.

I have not yet had success using Slic3r. Slic3r seems like the only raspberry pi compatible software. I know there is `cura` and `ultimaker`. It seems like I cant use `cura` or `ultimaker` on the Raspberry Pi, which leaves me with Slic3r.

Have read all the GitHub info.

Anybody willing to zoom connect to help me further?

Here are the instructions i used to install: https://plugins.octoprint.org/plugins/slic3r/

Here is the error message when attempting to execute:

```
pi@octopi:~/Slic3r $ ./slic3r.pl
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_GB.UTF-8").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_GB.UTF-8").
Can't locate Slic3r/XS.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Slic3r::XS module) (@INC contains: /home/pi/Slic3r/lib /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl5/5.28 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28 /usr/share/perl/5.28 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl-base) at /home/pi/Slic3r/lib/Slic3r.pm line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/pi/Slic3r/lib/Slic3r.pm line 37.
Compilation failed in require at ./slic3r.pl line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./slic3r.pl line 15.
```

Comment: `I have not yet had success using Slic3r.` what problem are you having with it? "no success" is meaningless - of course you've had no success, if you had success you wouldn't be asking :p

Comment: *Have read all the GitHub info* really? ALL github info? that's a LOT of info - or did you mean a specific github or two relating to your inability to make slic3r work?

Comment: @JaromandaX I am following the instructions from here: https://plugins.octoprint.org/plugins/slic3r/ But when I try to execute and run Slic3r after installation I get an error message, a perl warning. I am doing a redo on the installation. Once it finishes, I will upload the error message.  ---And thanks for being nice about it :-) always good to find someone who is cheerful about helping! I feel like an idiot! lol   I read and did the instructions on the main githubs like: https://github.com/slic3r/Slic3r/wiki/Running-Slic3r-from-git-on-GNU-Linux

Comment: have you tried searching for that error ... https://github.com/slic3r/Slic3r/issues/2402 may be of help ... there's others